# Cannot find reason for NullPointerException in Android App

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I am programming an Android app. Some users get a `NullPointerException` on Startup, but I cannot find the reason (on my Phone and 6 different AVDs it works and I cannot reproduce the exception so I could take a look on the error in my Android Studio and play around there).

The PlayConsole shows me this errorlog for my users. My knowledge is too small to get the reason just out of this log. Can anyone see the reason?

**Errorlog:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at de.schwembo.beercount.AuswertungFragment.onCreateView (AuswertungFragment.java:85)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java:2600)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
  at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps (BackStackRecord.java:439)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction (FragmentManagerImpl.java:1696)
  at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss (BackStackRecord.java:299)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate (FragmentPagerAdapter.java:235)
  at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate (ViewPager.java:1244)
  at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate (ViewPager.java:1092)
  at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure (ViewPager.java:1622)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:22286)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6668)
  at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild (CoordinatorLayout.java:760)
  at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild (HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:99)
  at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild (AppBarLayout.java:1892)
  at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure (CoordinatorLayout.java:831)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:22286)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6668)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:185)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure (ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:22286)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6668)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1539)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:823)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:702)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:22286)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6668)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:185)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:22286)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6668)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout (LinearLayout.java:1539)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical (LinearLayout.java:823)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure (LinearLayout.java:702)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:22286)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins (ViewGroup.java:6668)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure (FrameLayout.java:185)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure (DecorView.java:837)
  at android.view.View.measure (View.java:22286)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure (ViewRootImpl.java:2646)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy (ViewRootImpl.java:1674)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:1933)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1558)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:7463)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1041)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:847)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:774)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:1027)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:809)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:166)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7555)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:469)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:963)
```

The affected function (AuswertungFragment.java:85) is this, it is inside of the `onCreateView()` method:

```
// Spinner for Months differentiation
spinnerMonat.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
       // IF statement for year/gesamt selection
       if (spinnerMonat.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(getString(R.string.gesamt))) {
           for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
               alleDatenAusCursor = dataSource.zaehleAllesZuCursor(dataSource.getCursorFuerMonat(i + 1));
               anzahlZuMonate[i] = String.valueOf(alleDatenAusCursor[0]);
               preisZuMonate[i] = String.valueOf(alleDatenAusCursor[1]);
               mengeZuMonate[i] = String.valueOf(alleDatenAusCursor[2]);
           }
           fuelleLV4(monate, anzahlZuMonate, preisZuMonate, mengeZuMonate);
       } else {
           for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
               alleDatenAusCursor = dataSource.zaehleAllesZuCursor(dataSource.getCursorFuerMonatJahr(spinnerMonat.getSelectedItem().toString(), i + 1));
               anzahlZuMonate[i] = String.valueOf(alleDatenAusCursor[0]);
               preisZuMonate[i] = String.valueOf(alleDatenAusCursor[1]);
               mengeZuMonate[i] = String.valueOf(alleDatenAusCursor[2]);
           }
           fuelleLV4(monate, anzahlZuMonate, preisZuMonate, mengeZuMonate);
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
       for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
           alleDatenAusCursor = dataSource.zaehleAllesZuCursor(dataSource.getCursorFuerMonat(i + 1));
           anzahlZuMonate[i] = String.valueOf(alleDatenAusCursor[0]);
           preisZuMonate[i] = String.valueOf(alleDatenAusCursor[1]);
           mengeZuMonate[i] = String.valueOf(alleDatenAusCursor[2]);
       }
       fuelleLV4(monate, anzahlZuMonate, preisZuMonate, mengeZuMonate);
    }
});
```

dataSource is initialized in the `onCreate()` Method like this:

> `dataSource = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());`

Spinner is initialized in the `onCreateView()` Method like this:

> `final Spinner spinnerMonat = rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerMonth2);`

Comment: I don't know if this is the case, but I highly recommend using `equals` method on things, that are constant. This fragment of code: `spinnerMonat.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(getString(R.string.gesamt))` could potenntialy produce a nullPointer if e.g. getSelectedItem returns null. If you revert the equals: `getString(R.string.gesamt).equals(spinnerMonat.getSelectedItem().toString())`, if `getSeletctedItem` returns null, nullpointer won't be thrown.

Comment: NPE on that line would mean `spinnerMonat` is null. Do you have that fragment's layout varied in other configurations, such as `layout-land`, without `spinnerMonth2` there?

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much for this hint, i am so stupid. I have an alternative Layout for smaller screens which i didn't change. Also Thank you Embid for your hint, i also changed up that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was i had an alternative Layout which didnt include the spinner